# Create html links from list of folders in directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, dynamic

I would like to generate a list of hyper-links in my html navigation under one header (+WORKS), so that all I do is add a folder to a location on my server and my website will generate a link to that folder automatically so I do not need to change the code on all my pages in order to see it.

I would like it if someone can help me out with this but even pointing me in the right direction would be helpful as I'm an all around web developer newbie and don't know much of the capabilities of javascript and jquery or any other language besides html and css.

Thank you.

Comment: Generally speaking, JavaScript is executed on the client and as such has no access to your server's folder structure. What you could do would be to add a json or xml file with your Nav data, that would allow your nav to be constructed dynamically. Then you would update your nav file as you wanted to add/remove/rename nav items.

Comment: I know php is a server side script but I dont know if the host for my website has it installed.

Comment: I think almost all the webservers have PHP installed these days

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If PHP is an answer you could try this:

```
<?php
$dir    = '/path/to/folder';
$files1 = scandir($dir);

print_r($files1);
?>
```

EDIT
Sorr didnt read the question right the first time

try this

```
$files = scandir('/path/to/folder');
sort($files);
foreach($files as $file){
   echo'<a href="/path/to/folder/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>';
}
```

Comment: This would just print out the files in the directory, would php be able to create html hyperlinks?

Comment: No problem, thanks for the edit, I tried to do it myself but messed some stuff up, now would I be able to put this in my html code to go under a certain nav header or how would I call this? Thanks.

Comment: Yea of course, you can save it in a seperate file as "files.php" or something and then in another page you can use "include("path/to/file/");"